# Access parent view from custom cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview

How can I access the UIView in which I have a UITableView, from the custom cells inside that table. I cant find a method to do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an instance variable that points to the UITableView and set it when creating/configuring the cell (e.g. in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:). Make sure that your cell does not retain the tableView though.
Knowing your cell’s tableView, call [parentTableView superView] to access the UITableView’s parent view:

```
@interface PropertyListingCell : UITableViewCell {
    __weak id    parentTableView;
}

- (void) setParentTableView:(UITableView*)tv; // parentTableView = tv;
```

In UITableViewController implementation:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //dequeue/create and configure your custom cell here

    [cell setParentTableView:tableView];
    return cell;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you're using recent XCode (at least 4.3) you can simply add

```
@property (weak) UITableView *parentTableView; // use unsafe_unretained instead of weak if you're targeting iOS 4.x
```

to the `@interface` section of your UITableViewCell's subclass. Then, when you're creating a cell (in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`) set this property accordingly:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // ...
    //dequeue/create and configure your custom cell here
    // ...
    cell.parentTableView = tableView;
    return cell;
}
```

And in your cell class call `self.parentTableView` to access the tableView this cell belongs to.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but could u explain to me where this goes --------- @interface PropertyListingCell : UITableViewCell {
    __weak id    parentTableView;
}

- (void) setParentTableView:(UITableView*)tv; // parentTableView = tv;

Comment: The code in the top block shows what you have to add to your custom UITableViewCell header file (e.g. MyTableViewCell.h). `(id) parentTableView;` is basically a pointer to the tableView in the custom table cell implementation. `setParentTableView` is a method that sets the pointer to the table view - you should add it in your custom table cell implementation (e.g. MyTableViewCell.m). Now, when you are creating an instance of your custom cell in your UITableViewController subclass, you call your cell’s `setParentTableView` method and set pointer to the UITableView this cell belongs to.